# exporting layers to files and applying the background image to all layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a file with about 80 layers that I want to export to png's. That bit I know how to do but what I'm stuck with is how to include the background layer with every layer being exported? Each layer is on a transparent background but I want them all to have a logo which I only have on the base layer. Am I making sense? Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**An automated, easy solution**

1. Use the `File` → `Scripts` → `Export Layers to Files` script. This will export each layer of your document as a separate file with a filename that matches the layer name (so ensure your layer names are correct before running the script). Make sure you use a lossless 24bit format, like PNG (with 8bit alpha).
2. Delete the exported file that's the background layer. I assume you won't be needing it :)
3. Copy the background layer to the clipboard.
4. Create an action that pastes and reorders the layers so the pasted layer is in the background.
5. Run the action on all the files you exported.

If you need more detail on any of the steps, please let me know.

Comment: +1 For 80 files, this is the way to go. For only a few I would have gone with layer comps (or if the set needs to stay flexible, like a icon set in development).

Comment: @KMSTR: Using Layer Comps and then File—>Scripts—>Layer Comps to Files is not a bad way to go.  Fist create a Keyboard shortcut for Layer Panel menu > New Layer Comp and then quickly turn off/on the "changing" layer, then hit the mapped Keyboard short and repeat.  If there's 80-100 and it take about 2 seconds to press the key and turn on and off the layer he should be done within 3-4 minutes and then can use the script without all that extra clean-up as they will be the final as requested.  Cheers!

Comment: This worked like a champ. Brilliant solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Adobe Illustrator here is what you need to do.

You need to save your file in Illustrator format.

Download the script for exporting the png files while keeping certain layer visible (it does exactly what you want but in Illustrator):
[script](http://www.ericson.net/content/2010/10/export-layers-as-pngs/)

Then you need to add + to the background layer name (it will make  your background appear in all your exported images -- you can read more about it in the link.)

Change all the layer names to something other than the default name.

go to

```
File->Scripts->Export-Layers-as-PNG
```

Pick a location and you are done (for me it only works if i pick the location to be my desktop).

If you don't have Illustrator then you need to find/learn how to make/ask me to make/ a script that will do the same thing as the illustrator script does but for Photoshop.

You can try running the script with Photoshop by putting it in the Photoshop script folder and then going

```
 File->Scripts->Export-Layers-as-PNG
```

but it did not work for me.

good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest using the Timeline to do it and export each of the frames as a PNG, but in response to KMSTR, using Layer Comps and then File—>Scripts—>Layer Comps to Files is not a bad way to go actually.

First, create a Keyboard shortcut for Layer Panel menu > New Layer Comp (you can do this in Window—>Workspace—>Keyboard Shortcuts and Menus...).

Next, be sure your background layer is visible, then quickly turn off/on the "changing" layer(s), then hit the mapped Keyboard short and repeat turning off/on the changing layers and pressing the mapped shortcut.

If there's 80-100 and it take about 2 seconds to press the key and turn on and off the layer you should be able to make all of the comps in less then 5 minutes and then can use the script to generate what you want (files with background and selected visible layer—as layer comp) without all that extra clean-up (deleting, and then remerging with another action/script).

I hope this helps.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the alt key, and click the eye icon for the corrispondent layer, that will switch off everything but your layer, then reveal also the background layer (switch on the eye icon of it.)

Answer (score 0):

When you save a png any visible layers will be in the file. Simply leave the background layer visible along with whatever other layer/ you want to save, and hide any number of layers you don't want to see!

Hope this helps!